# Template Literals formatting / syntax issue

Tags: jquery, nested-loops, template-literals

I'm struggling because I have run this `for` loop with jQuery, but I can't get any output and I believe it is because my syntax for my template literals is messing up my code.  I don't know how to write that line properly, I've tried it many ways, but I can't get it to come back properly.  Thanks for your help!

```
let characterArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] //test
let propertiesArray = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] //test

function data() {
    for (let i=0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j < propertiesArray.length; j++) {
            `$('#${characterArray[i]}').attr('data-${propertiesArray[j]}', 
            ${characterArray[i]}.${propertiesArray[j]})`;              
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting the entire jQuery statement in the template literal?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What you have inside the `for` loops is not statements, it's just a string.

Comment: To follow up on what @GhassenLouhaichi is saying. If you console log what you have in `for` loop there *is* output?```console.log(`$('#${characterArray[i]}').attr('data-${propertiesArray[j]}', ${characterArray[i]}.${propertiesArray[j]})`);```

Comment: I'm making a game, and I have a series of objects that correspond to divs.  I want to insert those object keys into those divs as data.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript template literals are a way to construct complex/multiline strings, not statements. You can incorporate them within your jQuery statements as follows:

```
let characterArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] //test
let properties = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] //test

function data() {
    for (let i=0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j < properties.length; j++) {
            $(`#${characterArray[i]}`).attr(
                `data-${properties[j]}`,
                `${characterArray[i]}.${properties[j]}`
            );              
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`$('#${characterArray[i]}').attr('data-${properties[j]}', ${characterArray[i]}.${properties[j]})`;
```

Should be

```
$(`#${characterArray[i]}`).attr(`data-${properties[j]}`, `${characterArray[i]}.${properties[j]}`);
```

Each part that you want to transform into a string should be in the template, not the entire command.